# Bokeh DataRange1d: return to automatic updates of start/end

Tags: bokeh, bokehjs

In order to set axis ranges dynamically I use

```
x_range = DataRange1d(follow='end', follow_interval=duration, range_padding=0, range_padding_units="percent")
```

which updates the start/end property of the range dynamically as new data is plotted.

However, after usage of pan/zoom tool start/end points remain fixed. How do I turn the initial behavior back on?

I tried

```
plot.x_range.start = null;
```

but this yields

> Uncaught Error: DataRange1d(3320).start given invalid value: null